# How to return id after saving a record django rest frwamework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

How to return id after saving a record django rest frwamework.

I'm trying to get the saved object right after saving.

Registration is successful, but the id is not returned.

```
    empresa = EmpresaCreateSerializer(data=data)
    empresa.user = user_id
    if(empresa.is_valid()):
        empresa.save()
        print(empresa.id)
    else:
        return Response(empresa.errors)
```

> AttributeError: 'EmpresaCreateSerializer' object has no attribute
>   'id'

Model

```
class Empresa(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    cnpj = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome
```

Serializer

```
class EmpresaCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    nome = serializers.CharField(allow_blank=True, allow_null=True)
    cnpj = serializers.CharField(allow_blank=True, allow_null=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Empresa
        fields = ('id','nome', 'cnpj', 'user')
```

Comment: can you add your model and serializer

Comment: Model and Serializer added.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to assign the value being returned from the `save()` method:

```
obj = empresa.save()
print(obj.id)
```

The reason is that `save()` calls `create()` of the Serializer which returns an object instance

Comment: object is a class name so you should not use it. Rename it to some other variable name

Comment: I am doing the same thing but it returns `None`. here is my code `if 
  serializer.is_valid():
                visit_save = serializer.save()
                    print(visit_save.visit_id) # it returns None
                    print(VisVisits.objects.latest('visit_id')) # it return correct ids.` here i asked the same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54534706/access-auto-increment-primary-field-value-during-creation-of-a-record-with-djang)

Answer (score 4):

Hi you need do like this

```
empresa = EmpresaCreateSerializer(data=data)
empresa.user = user_id
if(empresa.is_valid()):
    empresa.save() //Here you need use these two methods **create,perform_create**
    print(empresa.data['id'])
```